# Ruby how to use regex to replace a part of a string and an additional part that is optional

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I am parsing strings in a log file, formatted in one of the following ways:

`[info] something written here`

or

`[info] - something written here`

In both cases, I need to return the:

`something written here`

The `-` is an optional addition to the log I am parsing.

I would like to have one regex to get the same result in both cases

I have tried:

```
line = "[info] - something written here"

line.gsub('[info] ',"")
```

Which results in

`- something written here`

How can I get rid of the optional `-`?

Comment: `\[info\][ -]*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line1 = "[info] something written here"
line2 = "[info] - something else written here"

line1.gsub(/\[info\] (- )?/,"") #=> "something written here""
line2.gsub(/\[info\] (- )?/,"") #=> "something else written here"
```

- You need to perform the `gsub` with a **regular expression**, not a `String`.
- Back-slashes are added to `\[` and `\]` to use the literal characters, rather than as brackets for a regex character set.
- `?` makes the capture group optional.

You could also consider making the pattern even more generic - e.g. to say "any number of spaces and hyphens": `/\[info\][- ]*/`

Comment: I've tried this but didn't work 
irb(main):164:0> line = "[info] - something"
irb(main):163:0> line.gsub('([info] (- )?',"$")
=> "[info] - something"

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were just using a `String` instead of a `Regexp`. Fixed.

Comment: I'd write this like `/\[\s*info\s*\]\s*\-?\s*/` because people often get sloppy with their formatting.

Comment: `\-?` -- that hyphen is unnecessary. `-?` works fine.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with `slice`?

Comment: @SagarPandya You *could*, but I don't see why you would. That's a more convoluted and inefficient solution. For example: `line.slice(/\[info\] (- )?(.*)/, 2)`

Comment: Right, I didn't know `slice` could take two arguments. I thought perhaps a one-argument `slice(regexp)` approach using a lookbehind, but couldn't quite see how it's done.

Comment: @SagarPandya Ruby, and most other languages, do not support non-deterministic (variable length) look-behinds. So this won't work: `line.slice(/(?<=\[info\] (- )?).*/)`. (And even if it did, like I said above, that's a more convoluted and inefficient solution!)

Comment: You don't need `gsub`. Use `sub`.

Comment: @TomLord @SagarPandya I also think that slice is better way to do this, but here is a little bit improved variant: `line2.slice(/\[info\]\s(?:-\s)?(.*)/,1)`